# Get Facebook posts having page name mentioned in it through /feed endpoint

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook page and I want to get the posts of all the Facebook users who mention my page name in their statuses. I'm trying to get these posts through `/feeds` but not able to get all the mentioned posts (even though these are public posts). Is there any other way to get these posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

Since Public Posts Search is deprecated according to the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog), there is no way to achieve this, i am afraid.

Comment: Currently I'm using the following url https://api.graph.facebook.com/{pagename}/feed to get all the page feeds which should include all the posts mentioning my page name, but I'm not able to get few posts.

Comment: well, that only gives you access to the posts of one specific page. if you don´t get all posts, maybe you are only using an app access token and the page is restricted by country or age?

Comment: Luschn I'll be able to see All the posts that will mention my page name in the posts to page box..I will be happy getting all the posts specific to a page but why I'm not getting few posts...however they are public posts? How to get them? Are you aware of other settings that will prevent the mention posts from appearing in the /feed of my page?

Comment: read my last comment, if the page is restricted you will see everything with your user account but NOT with an app token.